# Show that $(E, B(E), \sigma)$ is a measure space on a manifold $E$.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, manifolds

> Let
>
> $$E := \{x \in \Bbb R^5: x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R, x_3 = x_1 + x_2, x_4 = 1, x_5 = 2\}$$
>
> a manifold in $\Bbb R^5$. Furthermore, let $\sigma$ be the surface-measure defined by the chart $\phi: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow E$.
>
> Show that
>
> $$(E, B(E), \sigma)$$
>
> is a measure space. At first, show that $(E, B(E))$ is a measurable space.

I know that there are various theorems for showing that a function is measurable, but I have never proven that something is a measurable space. I looked up the definition for it, and it seems like that I only have to show that $B(E)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

But how would I have to do that? I don't know anything about $B(E)$ in this case. The $B$ might imply that it has something to do with Borel-sets, but that's all about it.

Does anyone know how to start about it?

Comment: I think $B(E)$ means just the Borel subsets of $E$. It's a $\sigma$-algebra by definition. What is left is to show that $\sigma$ assigns a measure to each Borel set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know if this argument holds though. It's quite likely that $B(E)$ includes the Borel subsets of $E$, but nonetheless, it could be literally anything else, couldn't it?

Comment: In principle, yes. But if it was not specified at all, what else it could be? If it was anything, you could hardly prove it is a $\sigma$-algebra... If it's from a textbook, look for a list of symbols near the beginning or the end.

Comment: You're probably right, it just looks weird as an excercise. :D